# Getting Error on npm, How can i solve this?

Tags: npm

```
npm start
```

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! path /home/saif/package.json
> npm ERR! errno -2
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/saif/package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent 
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/saif/.npm/_logs/2021-06-06T12_25_44_526Z-debug.log

Comment: Hello Islam, welcome to the community. When you will be sharing a problem, please, specify as many useful details you can provide. For example: in which directory are you running the command?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are inside your project directory , `there is no package.json` in this current directory '/home/saif/' thats why it couldnt run the script ,

if this is your project directory make sure your package.json exists